# It is possible send other data together with files in ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I'm uploading files through an Ajax interaction. I'd like to send, together, information in order to build a path in server side. But I don't know if it is possible and how I could do it.

```
function uploadFD(){

    var oMyForm = new FormData();

    jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        oMyForm.append('file-'+i, file);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'FileController',
        data: oMyForm,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
                $('#Result').html(data.msg);
                $.messager.show({
                    title : 'Success',
                    msg : data.msg,
                    showType : 'show'
                });
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,  headers = "content-type=multipart/*")
   public void upload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request, 
           HttpServletResponse response) {

     response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

     Iterator<String> itr =  request.getFileNames();

     MultipartFile mpf = request.getFile(itr.next());
     System.out.println(mpf.getOriginalFilename() +" uploaded!");
     //... other stuff
}
```

How could I do it? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `oMyForm.append()` to add other parameters to the form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
The second parameter to `FormData.append` can also be a simple string:

```
oMyForm.append('param', 'value');
```

and you can access the parameter value on the server via `request.getParameter()`:

```
String v = request.getParameter("param");
```